# Bash script to parse the output of a command

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sh, sha512

For instance command below

```
# sha512sum /home/bin.tar
```

gives this output:

```
7847a537b5db4434c075f18319caf12090cb0f19640190cbdf27e28a7b40b568127dfe9ec1c06604a87887ad403b618edeb42d1c41366b7a3e91d47b8d754ea4  /home/bin.tar
```

How can I assign only hash part of this output to a variable in bash in order to compare the calculated hash with other hash in another variable?

What I have tried only assigns the parts that matches condition in grep (I only need the first part):

```
#! /bin/sh

RESULT="$(sha512sum /home/bin.tar | grep -o " /home/bin.tar")"

echo "Result:"

echo $RESULT

exit
```

Output

```
Result: 
/home/bin.tar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RESULT="$(sha512sum /home/bin.tar | cut -d' ' -f1)"
```

or

```
RESULT="$(sha512sum /home/bin.tar)"
RESULT="${RESULT%% *}"
```

or

```
RESULT="$(sha512sum /home/bin.tar | grep -o '^[^ ]*')"
```

Comment: That was very quick and directly the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Do it with `awk`

```
RESULT="$(sha512sum /home/bin.tar | awk '{print $1}')"
```

Or using plain `bash` arrays. Just run these commands over the console.

```
md5Output=( $(sha512sum /home/bin.tar) ); printf "%s\n" ${md5Output[0]}
```

Comment: This also works well! Thank you!